# How to add event to element created with js?

Tags: javascript, events

I created the script below. It puts the body in a div, as desired. However, the event handler fails. I'm sure it's a simple error.

```
body_html = document.body.innerHTML;
new_html = "<div id='realBody'>" + body_html + "</div>";
document.body.innerHTML = new_html;
document.body.getElementById("realBody").addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {alert('body');});
```

How to make the event work? (Feel free to rewrite the whole thing if there's a better (simpler) way.

Edit: This works, some comments say it's the wrong way to put the body into a div, but i see no problems:

```
body_html = document.body.innerHTML;
new_html = "<div id='realBody'>" + body_html + "</div>";
document.body.innerHTML = new_html;
document.getElementById("realBody").addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {alert('body');});
```

thx!

Comment: Is the error you're getting `Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementById'`?

Comment: It should just be `document.getElementById`.

Comment: BTW, when your code runs, any event listeners attached to other elements in the body will be lost, because you're reparsing the HTML from scratch. It would be better to do it with DOM functions than replacing `innerHTML`.

Comment: @Barmar, how is that done?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cax11pd0/

Comment: @johnywhy `var container = document.createElement('div'); container.appendChild(document.body); document.body.appendChild(container);`

Comment: @Barmar can we move body as a child? or we have to move the contents of body

Comment: @Barmar, this is not working for me. I get the first alert, but not the second alert. My page then becomes blank.

var container = document.createElement('div'); 
container.id = 'BodyDiv';
container.appendChild(document.body); 
alert (container.innerHTML);
document.body.appendChild(container);
alert (document.body.innerHTML);

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work becaus appending it to the container detaches it from the document, so there's no more `document.body`. It would be easier if you had a container element in the original HTML that you could do this with. jQuery has a `.wrap()` method, but I'm not sure if it would work with `document.body`.

Comment: @Barmar, is that what mwilson is doing in his answer below, with the textnode? No, mwilson's solution does not work, see my comment there.

Comment: @ArunPJohny, is it necessary to have a while loop?

Comment: @Barmar with jQuery we have `wrapInner`

Comment: @johnywhy yes as body can have multiple children

Comment: This works, i don't understand what the problem is. I added this to the OP for better readability:

body_html = document.body.innerHTML;
new_html = "<div id='realBody'>" + body_html + "</div>";
document.body.innerHTML = new_html;
document.getElementById("realBody").addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {alert('body');});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `document.body.getElementById()` to `document.getElementById()`

```
document.getElementById("realBody").addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {alert('body');});
```

Comment: i like this answer because simple :) Other answers are also correct.

Answer (score 2):

You should attach event listener like,

```
body_html = document.body.innerHTML;
new_html = "<div id='realBody'>" + body_html + "I am border</div>";
document.body.innerHTML = new_html;
document.getElementById("realBody").addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
    alert('body');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xwvp31y8/)

Answer (score 2):

The error you're receiving is probably because of this line:

```
document.body.getElementById("realBody").addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) { alert('body'); });
```

you need to modify it to this:

```
document.getElementById("realBody").addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) { alert('body'); });
```

`document.body.getElementById()` just needs to be `document.getElementByid()`

A more proper way to add elements to the DOM would be to do something like below:

```
var divEl = document.createElement("div");
divEl.id = "realBody";
var textNode = document.createTextNode("Hover over me");
divEl.appendChild(textNode);
document.body.appendChild(divEl);

divEl.onmouseover = function (event) {
    alert('body');
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to create the div AND textnode?

Comment: No, but if you put an empty div within the dom, there's nothing there. I just created the textNode as a placeholder for whatever you're going to put in that div.

Comment: this is not doing what i need. Your new textnode gets the hover event, but the original body does not. I don't need to add new text, but i do need the original body to get the hover event.

Comment: So you're wanting to apply a hover event to the entire body? That will be fired quite a bit...

Answer (score 0):

As everybody explained, you need to call the getElementById() on the document object, not in an element.

But your code will loose any event handlers attached to the elements prior to your code execution as you are clearing the html and creating a new dom structure you overwritting the innerHTML.

Instead just move the existing dom to the new element like

```
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.id = 'realBody';
while (document.body.firstChild) {
    wrapper.appendChild(document.body.firstChild);
}
document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
wrapper.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
    console.log('body');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cax11pd0/)